# What is a use-case for multiple Tracers?

Tags: go, trace, open-telemetry

I'm implementing tracing feature with otel's official sdk tracing pacakge in Golang. The link for its repository is [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib).

While `TracerProvider` has all the configuraion such as `Exporter`, `SpanProcessor`, `Sampler`..., we can still choose different `Tracer`s from the same `TracerProvider`:

```golang
tracerA := otel.GetTracerProvider().Tracer("TracerA")
tracerB := otel.GetTracerProvider().Tracer("TracerB")
```

Since they are from the same TracerProvider, tracerA and tracerB behave the same. And there's no other setting that makes difference. Example below will make one trace, not separated traces.

```golang
ctx, span := tracerA.Start(context.Background(), "First Span")
ctx, span = tracerB.start(ctx, "Second Span")

// above becomes
|----------------------| // First Span
    |-------------|      // Second Span
```

I wonder why `otel` provides those different `Tracer` instances. The result is the same no matter which `Tracer` is used. Is there a use-case for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Tracer`s are used to distinguish [scope](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/a2a913a6dc72806749b2943ac64680cdc759dcde/specification/glossary.md#instrumentation-scope). A trace can indeed cross the boundaries of scope, but in order to show information flow within a system it is important to preserve the scope origin of a span.

For example, if you have one package that calls another and both packages are instrumented to record tracing telemetry, knowing what package a span comes from is critical if you want to track down a bug or performance question. For this reason, `Tracer`s need to uniquely identify instrumentation code. In the case of OpenTelemetry Go, [it is recommended](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace@v1.14.0#TracerProvider) that the `Tracer` name ...

> is the Go package name of the library providing instrumentation (note: not the code being instrumented).

That `Tracer` should only be used within that instrumentation package and any other package that is a part of an application should have its own `Tracer`.

The fact that all of these `Tracer`s originate from the same `TracerProvider`, and the `TracerProvider` is the object with all the export and processing configuration, means that all the telemetry these `Tracer`s will produce for an application is all processed and exported the same.